# Android: AsyncTask more priority than Service

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-service, thread-priority

I have a Service and AsyncTask running at the same time, Inside the service, storing the data in the server takes place, In AsyncTask, getting data from a different source and updating UI takes place.

UI doesn't get updated until the the task inside the Service gets completed, after that UI gets displayed

```
protected List<AppItem> doInBackground(MyTaskParams... integers) {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND + THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);
```

I used the above code for asynctask , but its not working, how can I give more preference to AsyncTask than Service

Comment: When do you start your service and when do you start your AsyncTask? Am I right that you first start your service and AsyncTask is started later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Service` runs on the Main thread.

> Remember that if you do use a service, it still runs in your
>   application's main thread by default, so you should still create a new
>   thread within the service if it performs intensive or blocking
>   operations.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=en#should-you-use-a-service-or-a-thread

It looks like you start your `Service` first, then you run your `AsyncTask`. Because the service runs in the `Main` thread, your AsyncTask is not started until it finishes.

**Update**

There are many solutions and the choice depends on requirements. It looks like in your case the simplest way to achieve concurrency is to use the `IntentService`. So, you can start both the `IntentService` and `AsyncTask` from your `Activity`.

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService 
{  

    private static final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.d(TAG, "MyIntentService Started");
        // This thing still happens on ui thread

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "MyIntentService Handling Intent");
        // Your work should be here, it happens on non-ui thread
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService

Comment: yea Service runs first, which I cant avoid, AsyncTask can start at anytime, when AsyncTask starts after Service, is there anyway I can resume the Service after AsyncTask

Comment: Yes, as it it is said above, you need to use a separate thread in your Service. Actually, now it even doesn't matter if you start it first or second, it will block your AsyncTask's onPostExecute anyway

Comment: Actually I'm using AsyncTask inside the service to do that particular task, still it happens, so it will block the onPostExecute, no matter what, and there is no solution?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please, try to use IntentService

Answer (score 2):

use this piece of code instead

```
 Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
```